# Resolving JSX syntax error when using CRA (create react app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to set up server side routing on a React project. Like always, I have used CRA. When I try to run the start command from my terminal, I get the error shown in the screen below:
[image]

Can anyone help me get past this? I think the problem is that I'm using CRA because from what I've read, there seem to be some extra steps I need to take in order to get my app to read my babel config files when using CRA. I can't quite figure it out though.
This is what my webpack.config.js file looks like:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
var browserConfig = {
  entry: './src/browser/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
    ]
  },
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "true"
    })
  ]
}
var serverConfig = {
  entry: './src/server/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'server.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "false"
    }),
  ]
}
module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig]
```

This is my index.js file inside the server directory:

```
import React from "react";
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import App from "../App";
const port = 8000;
const server = express();
server.use(cors());
server.use(express.static("public"));
server.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const markup = renderToString(<App />);
  res.send(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>SSR with RR</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">${markup}</div>
    </body>
  </html>
  `);
});
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server launched on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing to declare `@babel/preset-react` preset. Include at your `.babelrc` file along the other configurations:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ...
  ]
}
```

make sure that you have as your devDependency:

```
npm i -D @babel/preset-react
```